# R str_replace_all add parentheses or bracker in the replacement string

Tags: r

I have a data.frame like

```
                         Family                   Genus               Specie
JN692281.1.1537 Pseudomonadaceae             Azotobacter       Ambiguous_taxa
HM128723.1.1454 Pseudomonadaceae             Pseudomonas uncultured bacterium
KX177686.1.1460  Sneathiellaceae                AT-s3-44 uncultured bacterium
KR912339.1.1546 Desulfobulbaceae Candidatus Electrothrix       Ambiguous_taxa
GU179625.1.1501 Pseudomonadaceae             Pseudomonas       Ambiguous_taxa
```

so I want to replace all the taxons in Specie column that present **Ambiguous_taxa**, **metagenome** or **uncultured bacterium**, with Genus column data something like (Genus:data)-Unknown:

```
                         Family                   Genus               Specie
JN692281.1.1537 Pseudomonadaceae             Azotobacter       (Genus:Azotobacter)-Unknown
```

so I use this code:

```
#extract the tax_table with Phyloseq 
DF <- as.data.frame(tax_table(Phyloseq_obj))

#Replace with 
Unwanted <- c("Ambiguous_taxa|metagenome|uncultured bacterium")

DF$Specie <- str_replace_all(string = DF$Specie, pattern = Unwanted, (paste("(Genus:", DF$Genus, sep = "")))
```

I get :

```
                          Family                   Genus                         Specie
JN692281.1.1537 Pseudomonadaceae             Azotobacter             (Genus:Azotobacter
HM128723.1.1454 Pseudomonadaceae             Pseudomonas             (Genus:Pseudomonas
KX177686.1.1460  Sneathiellaceae                AT-s3-44                (Genus:AT-s3-44
KR912339.1.1546 Desulfobulbaceae Candidatus Electrothrix (Genus:Candidatus Electrothrix
GU179625.1.1501 Pseudomonadaceae             Pseudomonas             (Genus:Pseudomonas
```

And I want to close the parentheses and add Unknown: (Genus:Azotobacter)-Unknown

```
                          Family                   Genus                         Specie
JN692281.1.1537 Pseudomonadaceae             Azotobacter             (Genus:Azotobacter)-Unknown
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: You can have more than 2 arguments to `paste`. Just add a closing `")"` to the arguments you already have

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it with base R's `sprintf` function:

```
DF <- structure(list(code = c("JN692281.1.1537", "HM128723.1.1454", 
"KX177686.1.1460", "KR912339.1.1546", "GU179625.1.1501"), Family = c("Pseudomonadaceae", 
"Pseudomonadaceae", "Sneathiellaceae", "Desulfobulbaceae", "Pseudomonadaceae"
), Genus = c("Azotobacter", "Pseudomonas", "AT-s3-44", "Candidatus Electrothrix", 
"Pseudomonas"), Specie = c("Ambiguous_taxa", "uncultured bacterium", 
"uncultured bacterium", "Ambiguous_taxa", "Ambiguous_taxa")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                    -5L))
Unwanted <- c('Ambiguous_taxa', 'metagenome', 'uncultured bacterium')

DF$Specie[DF$Specie %in% Unwanted] <- sprintf('(Genus:%s)-Unknown', DF$Genus[DF$Specie %in% Unwanted]) 

             code           Family                   Genus                                  Specie
1 JN692281.1.1537 Pseudomonadaceae             Azotobacter             (Genus:Azotobacter)-Unknown
2 HM128723.1.1454 Pseudomonadaceae             Pseudomonas             (Genus:Pseudomonas)-Unknown
3 KX177686.1.1460  Sneathiellaceae                AT-s3-44                (Genus:AT-s3-44)-Unknown
4 KR912339.1.1546 Desulfobulbaceae Candidatus Electrothrix (Genus:Candidatus Electrothrix)-Unknown
5 GU179625.1.1501 Pseudomonadaceae             Pseudomonas             (Genus:Pseudomonas)-Unknown
```